# passportjs siempre direcciona a fail logon

Tags: html, nodejs, passport

Estoy intentando hacer un logon con passportjs pero por mas que coloco bien el usuario y password siempre me direcciona al fail logon.

Passport.js

```
module.exports = function(passport) {

  passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({ 
           usernameField: 'username',
           passwordField: 'password',
           passReqToCallback: true 
    },function(req, usuario, password, done) { 
           console.log(username+' = '+ password);
             request.query("SELECT * FROM tb_User WHERE usuario = 'daniel'", function(err, rows){
                console.log(err);
                if (err){
                    console.log('Error en query');
                    return done(req.flash('loginMessage', 'Error en query', err));
                }
                if (!rows.recordset.length) {
                    console.log('No se encontro usuario');
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'User or Password incorrect'));
                    // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash 
                }
                  //if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows.recordset[0].Password)){
                if(!user.verifyPassword(password=rows.recordset[0].Password)){    
                console.log('Error en password');
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'User or Password incorrect'));
                    // if the user is found but the password is wrong
                  }
                // all is well, return successful user
                console.log(rows.recordset[0]);
                return done(null, rows.recordset[0].usuario);
            });
        })
    );
```

router.js

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
                successRedirect : '/Home', // redirecciona a pagina pricipal
                failureRedirect : '/fail', // redirecciona a login
                failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
            }),
            function(req, res, info) {
                console.log("hello");
                res.render('/', {message: req.flash('loginMessage')});
        });
```

index.js

```
//Inicio de middleware ===========================================================
app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(morgan('dev')); // Loguea todos los request en la consola
app.use(cookieParser());// Lee los cookies (necesario para auth)
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
// requerido para inicio de passport
app.use(session({
    secret: 'session',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
 } )); // session secreta
app.use(flash()); // usa connect-flas para los mensajes flash guardados en la sesion
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistente login sessions

// routes ======================================================================
require('./js/passport')(passport); 
require('./js/router')(app, passport);
```

probe sacandole Bcrypt pero aun asi me sigue dando el mismo "error".

Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería.

Comment: Hola @Daniel, a mí me paso lo mismo que a ti y el error que cometí es en cómo nombraba los campos de entrada de "username" y "password" diferente. En tu caso, tú estas declarando los campos por defecto `{ usernameField: 'username'  ,passwordField: 'password'}'`, ¿es posible que los estes enviando con otro nombre en el body?